# Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar Does not fill the enitre screen

Tags: android, xamarin

When I try to inflate a custom action bar it never fills the entire screen.
It cuts of on the corners. Before I used Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar everything was working fine. Using Xamarin to develop my app not sure if this makes any difference or not

```
Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar mActionBar = this.SupportActionBar;

mActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
mActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.LoginActionBar);
```

code for LoginActionBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Please find the link to a screen shot here http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/cc29a398ec2da6cbbf6f43d1d7e95ca3.png

Comment: Please provide your `Resource.Layout.LoginActionBar`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Edit your question and put your code in that so that others can easily access it. Don't write code in comment. @CharlPotgieter

Comment: It would be interesting to see a screenshot

Comment: I have added a url to a screen shot

Comment: You'd better remove `android:orientation="vertical"`from `RelativeLayout`. I don't think it will do the trick, but still.

Comment: You might want to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JM-NkUwng1Y